# Subclassing commands.Bot vs instantiating it

Tags: discord.py

I usually see this in code:

```py
class MyBotClient(commands.Bot):
   async def on_ready()....

client = MyBotClient()
```

But I always do this in my code:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=....)
```

What is the difference between these two methods, and is there any advantage of either of them?

Comment: Subclassing the bot can be used in some cases such as `discord-components` to add some properties. But AFAIK its irrelevant if the only method is on_ready. And they don't support commands (not without hacky workarounds).

Comment: By `they don't support commands` I mean commands inside MyBotClient class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Customizability, Maintainability and Code Cleanliness

The difference is mainly customizability, maintainability and code cleanliness.

### Code Cleanliness

I had like 10 variables that are an attribute of client, e.g.

```py
bot = commands.Bot(...)
bot.x = ""
bot.y = 1
bot.z = 0.2
# and so on to like 10 lines...
```

when I created my own class, I put it in another file and the class is like

```py
class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.x = ""
        self.y = 1
        self.z = 0.2
        # and so on...
```

Now my main file just cleanly creates the bot and runs it, simple, but this is mainly because it's open-source

### Customizability

> Subclassing allows you to extend, expand, and even diminish, or
> degrade, the existing functions and coroutines. Perhaps to add extra
> validation of parameters, perform additional processing to the
> original function, or even to change the purpose of the function or
> coroutine altogether.

From [What Are the Benefits of Subclassing (Visual Basic)](https://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/What_Are_the_Benefits_of_Subclassing.htm#:%7E:text=Subclassing%20allows%20you%20to%20extend,the%20function%20or%20subroutine%20altogether.)
You can add/change so much with a subclassed bot, for example, you can make a custom context class that is returned instead of the usual commands.Context, this would allow you to add custom functions/attributes to even the context. One of the things I did is that I overrode the send method of my custom context so that it replies to the user on every command

### Maintainability

This kinda falls under code cleanliness as it makes the code easier to maintain/change in the future. Like all your events can stay in one place, and even in my example before, I had like 140 commands at the time, I wanted the bot to switch to the new discord reply system, I didn't need to replace ctx.send with ctx.reply everywhere in each file, I just overrode the send to use reply unless it's explicitly disallowed